# Two Pokemon with same CP, one is wonder one is not, does it matter which I use in a battle?

Tags: pokemon-go

If I have two Pokemon of the same type and attacks and with the same CP, but one is a 'wonder' and the other is 'not likely to make much headway in battle' when appraised, does it matter which one I use in battle?

While this has been marked as duplicate, none of the suggested duplicates actually answers this question.

Comment: Appraisal talks about _potential_, not current stats.

Comment: duplicate? The other question is about Can the same CP have diffrent stats. This one is about, Does it matter if i use two pokemon with diffrent stats but the same CP.. Fair enough that the answers are trying to answer the first question but that is not what OP is asking.

Comment: The questions are similar, but I believe the other regards powering up while this is about gym battling.  @Ezward, you might try editing your question based on your comments below.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you didn't post images, it's not possible to know for sure, but if you have two of the same species of Pokémon with the same CP but one is a wonder and the other is not likely to make much headway in battle, then they are likely not the same level.

The wonder Pokémon should have less of the semicircle above it filled in compared to the one that's not likely to make much headway in battle. Thus, you should absolutely train up the one that's a wonder.

While they may have the same CP now, they will have a large gap in their CP cap when they are the same level.

Also, it's worth noting that movesets will not influence whether a Pokémon is a wonder or not.

Comment: This answer is wrong, the appraisal feature measures IV's, not stardust level.

Comment: @LukeB. I never said that it didn't, hence the part about the semicircle above the Pokémon themselves, which *does* indicate stardust level. What I said was that they aren't the same level, since they have the same CP but different IVs.

Comment: You are correct that the wonder is lower level that the not likely (it's semicircle is not as full).  My question is more a about whether that matters in a given battle.  If I use the wonder or the not likely given the CP they are currently at (which is the same),  will the wonder be more likely to win?  Will I receive more reward if I use the wonder and win, since it is a lower level?

Comment: No the rewards for battling are solely dependent on CP. In terms of *right now*, it doesn't matter which one you choose to use. In the future, the wonder will outperform the not likely. Even if you level them both up once, the wonder will have higher CP than the other.

Comment: @LukeB. I think you've misunderstood the part of this answer that talks about the Pokemon's level.

Answer (score 3):

When you select the option to examine a pokemon, the head of your team will look at the so-called IV (individual values) of the pokemon. In the end, the individual values do not make a huge difference when it comes to the combat strength of a pokemon.

If you have two pokemon of the same type, using the pokemon with the highest CP is usually the best option, as it takes less stardust to upgrade it. If you have two pokemons of the same type with the same CP, use the one with the best IV's.

Comment: So in this case, the appraisal is enough to tell me that the wonder has better IV.  Will this make any reseal difference to the outcome?  Will it make any difference in the rewards that are received, like gym prestige?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that it will not matter.

Prestige and xp is dependant on attacker CP compared to defender CP.

Because of how stats are distributed, you might have a minimal diffrence in how the fight goes if you can dodge because HP and Defence stats won't matter as much as if you take all hits.

(so if one has IVs of 15/0/0 and the other 10/15/15, the first might end up a better fighter for you.)

Answer (score -2):

Use the one who have best IV ;) 
You can search their IV by appraise in game or on google try to find IV calculator :)

Comment: I know the wonder will have the best IV because of the appraisal, don't I?

Comment: Yes you can know it by appraise, but i prefer app i think its more accuracy :)